# Keeping buttons on same line as text

Tags: html, css

I have a liste of items where buttons are only visible when hovering the corresponding line.

[image]

**The problem is** when the title is taking all the width then the buttons are swapped below. Example on the 3rd line of this list (see below).

[image]

How to have buttons staying in place and having the text reduced like showed below..

[image]

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: Try giving `z-index` of on-hover buttons container more than the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use flex and align-item property to solve your problem.

```css
p {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

h2:hover+p {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Hello there</h2>
  <p>icon
    <p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Restrict the width of the text div like this

```
.text-div {
    max-width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

Comment: Chances are that a static `max-width` won't look great with different widths

Comment: Good shout. Should probably control it using media queries.

Comment: You probably could, but even then you'd be hardcoding in values. You can use a `flex` layout to keep the elements snug against one another, so that the width of `text-div` is already set